# AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in the very early stages of learning Python. (Disclaimer, I am in school, and this is a homework question). I am attempting to create a program that will divide wedding guests into a side of the room, based on their name alphabetically. However, when I run my program, I am getting an error message that reads, "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python36\Wedding Guests Program.py", line 29, in 
    root.data.append("M") #M is halfway through the alphabet. Depending on the group, this may need to change
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'data'"

I reached out to a tutor at my school, but when they ran the program on their computer, it ran correctly. I am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction of where I have messed up. Here is my code:

```
class Node:
    def _init_ (self, left, right, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = list () #Using a list for people with the same first name
def addGuest (root, guest) : #Defining left requirements
    if guest < root.data [0] :
        if root.left == None:
            root.left = Node ()
            root.left.data.append (guest)
        else:
            addGuest (root.left, guest)
    else: #Defining right requirements
        if guest > root.data [0] :
            if root.right == None:
                root.right = Nide ()
                root.right.data.append (guest)
            else:
                addGuest (root.right, guest)
        else:
            root.right.data.append (guest)
def printGuest(root) :
    if root == None:
        return
    print(root.data)
    printGuest (root.left) #printing left and right so both sides of the room are represented.
    printGuest (root.right)
root = Node()
root.data.append("M") #M is halfway through the alphabet. Depending on the group, this may need to change
for i in range (0,8): #Choosing 8 to ensure it divides evenly. This can be changed
        addGuest (root, input("Add Guest"))
print ("Left side:")
printGuest (root.left)
print("Right Side:")
printGuest (root.right)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your in the Node class `_init_` should be `__init__`. This means the `self.data = list()` is never assigned. Also, the more pythonic way of creating a list is `self.data = []`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Node class, make sure double underscores before "init" constructor ("**init**()") and **init**() passing three arguments, to create an instance you should pass 3 arguments or set the default value of them.
    root = Node()
to
   root = Node(left, right, data) # left, right, data means the value of left, right, data

Otherwise, you will get below error:
 **TypeError**: **init**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'left', 'right', and 'data'

Anyway, you can remove **left, right** from the arguments list as it has no uses in the **init**() function.